# Verifying Value is Not Equal Before Assigning Value

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

Is there any point checking to see if a value has already been assigned to a variable or is it better to just simply assign the value? For example, if X is going to equal 1, is there any point checking to see if X already equals 1? Example code below:

```
if X != 1 {
    X = 1
}
```

I ask this question become I'm looping through a bunch of children sprites and changing the alpha values to 0, which most are already set at 0. So I'm seeing if there is any benefit in checking the children's alpha value first (I can't see the benefit).

```
parent.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "*", using: {
    node, stop in

    // if node.alpha != 0 {

    node.alpha = 0

    // }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the value normally.

What even is the point of checking whether the value is already 0 before setting it? What difference does it make? After the line of code:

```
node.alpha = 0
```

No matter what value `alpha` has before, it will *always* be 0 after the above line!

If you are worried about performance, **don't**, until you encounter one.

Setting `alpha` is just like setting any other variable. It doesn't do much apart from setting the value. It won't immediately change the alpha of the sprite on the screen. It will only do it in the next frame.

Say you do this a bunch of times:

```
for _ in 0...10000 {
    node.alpha = 0
    node.alpha = 1
}
```

The node's alpha on the screen won't be flashing like crazy. Eventually it will be 1 so the node will be drawn with alpha = 1 in the next frame.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. I figured what I've been doing is fine, but wanted to make sure there were no repercussions. I wasn't sure if changing a value (even if its to the same value) created unnecessary re-processing or something.